# HIVE Query for finding the sum of all child node value

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a HIVE table which values are like below:

```
id  parent_id   value   lavel
A   A             10    L1
B   A             15    L2
C   A             10    L2
D   B              5    L3
E   B              5    L3
I   C             10    L3
F   D             10    L4
G   D             10    L4
H   E              5    L4
```

This table can be summarized as below diagram:

[image]

I want a hive query which will give value of a node which is sum of all child
For example: Value of D :F+G=20
Value of B :D+F+G=25

Appreciate any suggestions....Thanks in advance

Comment: As per your question, value of B shouldn't be D+F+G+E+H??

Comment: Yes....you are right KamalNaruka